# How can I get list of Applications as shown in Task Manager (Not Processes)

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to obtain a list of the Applications currently running using a Windows Application.

```
    using System.Diagnostics;
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        List<string > listProc=new List<string>() ;
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            listProc.Add(p.ProcessName );               
        }
        string joined = string.Join(",", new List<string>(listProc).ToArray());
        ScriptingObject.WriteLogMessage("List of Processes: " + joined , true);
```

I also tried this:

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                listProc.Add(p.MainWindowTitle);

            }
```

These work fine listing the Processes listed by the Windows Task Manager, but how do I see the Applications listed under the Applications Tab?

The first option lists more processes than the 2nd, and I see even more if I run as Administrator, but I am still not seeing all the Applications I can see listed by the Task Manager.

I think the Application I am looking for might be described as a Child Window.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I have the same problem ...

Answer (score 1):

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
List<string > listProc=new List<string>() ;
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    if (p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32()>0)
    {
        listProc.Add(p.MainWindowTitle);
    }               
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to enlist only those process which are visible to Window, You can try this,

```
if (p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            listProc.Add(p.MainWindowTitle);

        }
```

Comment: Does not find my Application.