# C#: How to list working processes on my PC same as Task manager (NOT LIKE APPLICATONS TAB)

Tags: c#, process, taskmanager

I want to list working process on my pc in my listview as a Task Manager (not all processes).

I tested that samples and many of them:

[How can I get list of Applications as shown in Task Manager (Not Processes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086385/how-can-i-get-list-of-applications-as-shown-in-task-manager-not-processes)
[How to list all Windows Processes and their attributes (Task Manager like) with C# in WinForms](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/439/how-to-list-all-windows-processes-and-their-attributes-task-manager-like-with-c-in-winforms#disqus_thread)

I want to list that applications:
[My task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAYuH.png)

I can list that ones in my listview:
[Listed proccesses in my list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfcUJ.png)

I used that lines in my code:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(p.MainWindowTitle);
            }
        }
```

But this one is listing like Nvidia Geforce Now, Groove Music or Microsoft Text Input Application etc. These are not listing in Windows Task Manager. How can  I eliminate that ones.

Answer (score 0):

In the TaskManager, processes are displayed in two modes :

> 1. The first mode of programs that have an icon in the Taskbar(More Details)

```
List<Process> taskBarProcesses = Process.GetProcesses().
                                        Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
                                        .ToList();
```

> 2. Programs that do not have an icon in the taskbar(Fewer Details)

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process p in processes)
{
     Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName);
}
```